# Django - how to get the value in the ListView from the HTML?

Tags: django, listview

Using Django, I have created the Book class and the BookManager class in the models.py. The BookManager class has the method to count the number of the book title containing the keyword. How can I show the book title count to the HTML file using the Classe-based view?

I know how to do it using the function-based view but not with the ListView class based view.

```
models.py
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class BookManager(models.Manager):
    def title_count(self, keyword):
        return self.filter(title__icontains=keyword).count()


class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    publication_date = models.DateField()
    page_length = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)

    objects = BookManager()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

views.py

from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import ListView

from .models import Book

class BookViewPage(ListView):
    model = Book
    title_number = Book.objects.title_count('django')

def bookviewpage(request):
    context ={
        'count': Book.objects.title_count('django')
    }
    return render(request, 'books/book_list.html', context)
```

I want to display the book title count on the HTML file using the Classe-based view.

Comment: Will `{{ object_list|length }}` work?

Comment: Can you show your CBV?

Comment: I edited the question. It shows the models.py and the views.py.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add items to the context of class based views by overriding the `get_context_data` method.

```
class BookViewPage(ListView):
    model = Book

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(BookViewPage, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['title_number'] = Book.objects.title_count('django')
        return context
```

Now you can use `{{ title_number }}` in the template.

Putting `title_number = Book.objects.title_count('django')` in the view doesn't work, because this code runs when the module is loaded, not when the view handles the request.

Comment: Great! It worked. It didn't come to my mind that I should use the get_context_data. I need more coding. Thanks a lot.